# Manually mount a globally registered Vue component into a legacy app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js, vuejs2

I am converting an AngularJS project to Vue 2.

My strategy is to have AngularJS handle routing, and slowly swap out individual components within each angular view.

In my `main.ts` file, I'm importing and defining global components like this:

```
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm.vue';
Vue.component('LoginForm', LoginForm);
```

When the relevant Angular controller loads, I'd like to run some javascript to manually mount the Vue component.

Is this a good approach?

How can I manually mount a previously registered component?

`Vue.somehowGetComponent('LoginForm').mountTo('#login-form');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't register it as a global component for this purpose. Simply import it, then create an instance of it and mount it. eg.

```
  // import the component
  import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm.vue';

  // If you haven't already, must call `Vue.extend` on LoginForm before its instantiation

  const myLoginForm = new LoginForm();

  // mount to your legacy app
  myLoginForm.$mountTo(document.getElementById('login-form'));
```

Comment: Thanks for that feedback! How can I `import` it in my legacy code if it isn't converted/transpiled in babel like the rest of the Vue app is?

Comment: I'd use a global variable on window scope. Not the nicest, but you are essentially doing this with your globally registered Vue component solution. If you put it in some kind of object window.VUES_LEGACY_ANGULAR.LoginForm its a bit easier to search for if you ever need to refactor.

Comment: I'm unable to run `new LoginForm()`. Any idea why? everything else is the same as your example (`import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm.vue';`

`Uncaught TypeError: window.VueComponents.LoginForm is not a constructor`

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. Generally I use Vue.extend when defining before exporting. Also would recommend any window globals are stored in a container object, small thing but makes it easier to track them. However the main thing is you got it working!

Comment: Yes, thanks for your help! Saved me lots of time. I'll give you the check for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The key here was calling `Vue.extend` on my imported component:

In Vue.js:

```
// main.ts
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm.vue';
window.LoginForm = Vue.extend(LoginForm)
```

Then in the AngularJS controller:

```
angular.module('app').controller(function(){
    var vue = new window.LoginForm();
    vue.$mount('#login-form');
});
```